# mvvmcross v3 CirriousConference deploy failure

Tags: mvvmcross

I just did a git clone of MVVMCross v3 and did a Deploy project to a Gingerbread Virtual Machine.

Seven of the examples deployed without issues, but when the CirriousConference app deployed I got an error message about a missing shared library. See [this screenshot](https://plus.google.com/photos/109040001860227423704/albums/5860859816613199409?authkey=CPqtl_KuucLETg).

Environment: VS2010, Xamarin 4.6.49, Windows 8.

I tried restarting the emulator and rebooting the computer without success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This type of error is often caused by the emulator image not having any Google Maps installed.

For the ARM emulators, you can create new emulators including Google Maps by adding the Google SDK packages

For the x86 emulator, try this post - http://www.seal.io/2012/09/android-x86-images-with-google-sdk-maps.html - I've not used it, but I've heard good things about it recently.

---

Alternatively, you can remove the maps functionality from that sample - it is only used on the hotel map page.